# Chat missing from top and bottom of the page

Tags: discussion

From [Privileges | Chat Rooms](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms):

> There is a link to chat in the footer of every page. The link also
>   appears in the Stack Exchange site switcher on the upper right corner
>   of every page. Click one of those links, and then click the "create a
>   new room" button at the bottom of the Rooms page...

All of them seem to be missing.

Comment: It's not in the footer anymore but it's definitely in the site switcher.

Comment: I guess the privilege description needs updating...